# I'm valuable to many, especially to those who need me

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.
> Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.
>
> Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.
> Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.
>
> So by me, men are made mortal.

What am I?

Comment: "I'm valuable to many, especially to those who need me" so, every object in the universe. Next!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> Blood

Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.

> if you see blood, in real life or in horror movies, horrors may await

Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.

> Well, blood vessels are kinda straight.  kinda.

Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.

> Cut someone and a lot of blood cells will pass by (perhaps a city's worth)

Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.

> many "dressed up" poetic references to death and blood. (thanks OP!)

So by me, men are made mortal.

> indeed, without blood, death is there

Title

> Blood is very valuable to those who need transfusions.

Acrostic

> Bonds.  Refers to the bond of family (blood) or a bond as strong (blood brothers)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. As for the second to last line, rot13(Cbrzf qerff hc oybbq naq qrngu jvgu qrfpevcgvbaf.)

Comment: I did not see that coming lol! +1

Answer (score 5):

Would you happen to be:

> The hangman's noose?

*Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.*

> People are terrified of the noose.

*Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.*

> After flailing a bit, life leaves the body and it becomes limp and straight.

*Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.*

> When the noose was traditionally brought out, city-wide gatherings would occur.

*Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.*

> Most were asked if they had final words, this could be paying homage to that.

*So by me, men are made mortal.*

> Men are definitely proven mortal by the noose.

Hidden Acrostic:

> BONDS $\leftarrow$ My first thought was to bail bonds (due to the title), but it didn't fit. However, most victims of the noose are bound in chains; which in older times were referred to as bonds.

Comment: I'm really curious to see your reasoning behind this answer, especially concerning the third line.

Comment: Well it is now available lol

Comment: Nice answer! $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> Police

Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.

> If they are there it means that there is trouble somewhere.

Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.

> On the highway?

Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.

> They can stop road traffic and then there will be a build up.

Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.

> They have a law?

So by me, men are made mortal.

> They fight against criminals.

Acrostic

> Jail bonds?

Comment: In reference to your poems portion, Miranda Rights fit well (but not the dying part, but this could be a metaphor). +1 Great answer!

Comment: Wow, another really interesting take on this puzzle. +1 These are way different than what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure but there are a few lines in particular that give me a guess.

Are you ......

> A Bridge

Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.

> Going over a bridge means you're passing over something dangerous (a river, gorge, or maybe even a troll), or may be entering an unfamiliar place where you should be cautious.

Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.

> A bridge that runs into free space could end a life, but bridges are generally quite straight

Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.

> As soon as a bridge is opened everyone tries to use it as it's generally the best available route.

Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.

> Bridges attract graffiti and other art, especially when old and out of repair.

So by me, men are made mortal.

> Bridges are a well known way for people to end their lives.

Hidden Acrostic:

> BONDS ← Bridges bond otherwise inaccessible places.

I'm not very confident but wanted to guess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer has been found already, but let me give it a shot.

Are you

> Time

Beware if you see me, great horrors may await.

> When you see your last hours come along, you'll die soon.

Over where I run free, in me life runs straight.

> Time can neither be stopped or reverted and keeps ticking straight.

Nick me open, a city's worth of traffic passes by.

> Lot of traffic in cities, speccialy at rush hours.

Dressed in poems, especially when one is about to die.

> Many "dressed up" poetic references to death and time. (Stole this one from @SteveV)

So by me, men are made mortal.

> When someone's time has come for him to go.

Title

> "Time is a valuable thing watch it fly by as the pendulum swings." (In the end - Linkin Park)

Acrostic

> Bonds.  Investments to make profit over time.